# Existence of a Schmidt group of a specific order

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I am trying to find a Schmidt group (i.e. a minimal non-nilpotent group) $G=P\rtimes Q$ (the kernel is $P$) of order $p^aq$ which satisfies the following conditions:

1. $p, q$ are odd primes such that $p<q$; $a\geq 3$;
2. $P$ is a non-abelian $p$-group of order $p^a$ (the exponent of this group would be $p$, since $p$ is odd);
3. $(p^{a-r+1}-p+1)(q^2-q+1)\geq p^aq$, where $r$ is the multiplicative order of $p$ modulo $q$.

What I've tried so far: I wrote a code to find some examples of pairs $(p, q)$ such that condition 3) holds. For instance, if we suppose that $a=4, r=3$ and we run through a list containing the first $1000$ odd primes, we get $(p, q)\in \lbrace (3, 13), (5, 31), (17, 307), (41, 1723), (59, 3541), (71, 5113)\rbrace$. Using these numbers and GAP, I tried to find a Schmidt group having the properties described above. However, in most situations, the order of such a potential group is large and GAP's AllSmallGroups library does not include information about such orders. My question would be if there is any theoretical result which guarantees the existence of a Schmidt group which satisfies the outlined conditions? Eventually, can we point out a specific example or say something more about the structure of such a group (for instance, something about the structure of $P$)?

From what I've noticed so far, there are quadruples $(p, q, r, a)$ such that we cannot construct a Schmidt group satisfying the above conditions. Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: I do not know theoretical results about Schmidt groups.
But if we take $p=3$, $q=13$ and $a=6$, then condition (3) still holds and there are three non-Abelian groups $A_i$ of order $3^6$ which have automorphisms of order $13$. Are the groups $A_i\rtimes C_{13}$ are Schmidt groups?

Comment: @kabenyuk I haven't thought much about it, but I would not expect them to be Schmidt groups, because the $C_{13}$ would need to act irreducibly on $A/\Phi(A)$, so we would get $|A/\Phi(A)| = 3^3$, but that would force $\Phi(A)=Z(A)$ elementary abelian and then $\Phi(A) \rtimes C_{13}$ would be non-nilpotent.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. There is a Schmidt group of order $3^6\cdot 13$ (SmallGroup(9477, 505)). Unfortunately, its structure description is $C_{13}\rtimes C_{729}$, but we would need a kernel of order $3^6$.